# Why I get a "Active schema does not support the element"?

Tags: visual-studio-2003, ultrawingrid

I'm working with Visual Studio 2003 and ultra grid.
In my html code I can see tag error like

```
active schema does not support the element...
```

However, I don't see any problem to execute my web application. I just wanted to know why I am getting Tag error. Is it because of third party tool ultrgrid?

Comment: Post code please. Most infragistics errors are due to version conflicts anyway.

Comment: VS2003 is pretty broken... you should upgrade to 05 or 08 if you can. may help out a lot with dumb errors that aren't necessarily your fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visual studio designer has its own HTML schema validator. You may see HTML validation errors in design mode eventhough the website works fine.

It could be that Infragistics assemblies are loading from the GAC and not the "bin" directory of the website.

Make sure that your references to the Infragistics assemblies are set to "Copy Local". Please refer to [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community_Server/re-22336_The_Active_schema_does_not_support_the_element_DisplayLayout_AddNewBox_Bands_etc.aspx) for more information.

Comment: yes i set the Copy Local property to true...but still im getting the same error

Comment: If the "Copy Local" property was not set previously, you could try rebuilding the solution. Otherwise, my only other suggestion is upgrading to VS2005 or 2008.

Comment: yea i tried to rebuild the the solution too...
not working..
hope it wont create any problem...
Thank you Jose

Answer (score 1):

The IDE validates your HTML to a schema - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41xb5fe7(VS.71).aspx).
You could try to put valid HTML (if its not) or add a schema to use (details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa713983(VS.71).aspx)).